# How to properly use GroundDb for Meteor?

Tags: meteor

It is not quite clear by looking at the documentation if I correctly converted my typical online meteor app to an offline app.

It seems to be working ok, but I do notice some delay before the data is loaded. I am also wondering if I should be doing anything else to help to make a better user experience

Here is what I am doing.

For each collection my app depends on, I grounded the collection by using the code

```
Ground.Collection(Meteor.users) 
Ground.Collection(ExampleCollection)
```

Since I am using Iron Router waitOn, and arunoda's subs manager for caching. I only wait and subscribe if connected like so:

```
  waitOn: ->
    if Meteor.userId()?
      if Meteor.status().connected
        [
          subs.subscribe 'myInfo'
        ]
```

And that all really. Thats why I am wondering if there is anything I am missing or anything I can do it improve it. I have tested it locally and it seems to be working, but I do notice a slight delay.

Here is how I believe it is working.

When you first use the app you have to be online to create an account, signup, and create your profile, etc. So while online all the subscription data is saved to minimongo. Because I have grounded each collection on startup it is also saved to local storage.

Then when it goes offline, anytime the app needs data from the collection, it still works because any collection data subscribed to while online is still saved when offline.

So besides this small amount of code I added, is there anything else I am missing?

Is it possible to still show the loading animation while fetching from local storage? Like we have progress animation for iron router?